# Liferay DLFileEntry image conversion is not fully converting the image

Tags: java, image, liferay, scale

I am converting an image as a DLFileEntry from JPG to PNG format using the following code.

```
    try {
        DLFileEntry dlFileEntry = DLFileEntryServiceUtil.getFileEntry(dlFileEntryId);
        InputStream inputStream = dlFileEntry.getContentStream();

        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int nRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
        }
        buffer.flush();
        byte[] byteArray = buffer.toByteArray();

        ImageBag imageBag = ImageToolUtil.read(byteArray);
        RenderedImage renderedImage = imageBag.getRenderedImage();
        if (renderedImage == null) {
            throw new IOException("Unable to decode image");
        }

        renderedImage = ImageToolUtil.scale(renderedImage, 2000);

        buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(renderedImage, "png", buffer); 
        InputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toByteArray());

        DLAppServiceUtil.updateFileEntry(
                dlFileEntry.getFileEntryId(),
                dlFileEntry.getName(),
                MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE,
                dlFileEntry.getTitle(),
                dlFileEntry.getDescription(),
                "",
                true,
                fis,
                buffer.size(),
                serviceContext);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Even though it updates the image content type and extension in "Documents and Media", when we try downloading the image, it is still in JPG format.

[image]

The image looks like above in Documents and Media. You can see that the content type has become `image/png`.

[image]

Above shows the screenshot while I tried to Download this image and save it. It is still in the original format of JPG when I try downloading. What should I do in addition to the code above, inorder to completely convert the image to PNG?

Comment: Did you check, if the server is really returning the wrong content type? I had once a problem where a browser (the one starting with "I") always wanted to save even PNG images as JPG files. So please try in other browsers as well.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke  I tried with IE, Firefox and Chrome. Same result. They are all saving the image as JPG

Answer (score 1):

You still store the old file name: `dlFileEntry.getName()`

I would guess that `jpeg` or `jpg` is the extension of the old file name and the browser determines his file filter from the extension.

So better exchange the extension as well:

```
DLAppServiceUtil.updateFileEntry(
    dlFileEntry.getFileEntryId(),
    dlFileEntry.getName().replaceAll("\\..*?$",".png"),
    ...
```

This will change the extension that is stored for that file

Comment: I am sorry, but that did not fix the issue. :-(

Comment: You should check two things: Is the stored file a png (open it in an hex editor and check if it starts with `0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47`)? How does the HTTP response header of the image look like (either with the developer tools of your browser or with _wget_)?

Comment: in hex editor, it starts with `0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47`. In the HTTP header, it shows `Cache-Control → private`,`Content-Disposition → inline; filename="Nature01.jpg"`,`Content-Length → 12499600`,`Content-Type → image/jpeg`...

Comment: Can you show the URL that was produced for your download? Because if that contains a `fileName` parameter, that will override any file name that was set for your DLFileEntry.

Comment: No. it does not contain a fileName parameter.. URL is `/documents/20181/24140/Nature01/67156ee9-1e6a-4595-b79a-dc24bbd10ba5?version=3.0&t=1449505888000`

Comment: Ok, last things you could check: Is the extension in the database still "jpg" for your version? Maybe not only the file name but the title still contains the extension as well?

Comment: Yeah .. it is still "jpg". I tried to manually update this with "png", but it was not solving the problem.